# Find the maximum element in an array which is first increasing and then decreasing

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

I made a code and compiled for below input it is correct 
 as

```
 Input: arr[] = {8, 10, 20, 80, 100, 200, 400, 500, 3, 2, 1}
```

Output: 500

```
 Input: arr[] = {1, 3, 50, 10, 9, 7, 6}
```

Output: 50

```
int findIncre_Decre(int arr[], int low, int high)
  {
        if (low == high)
        return arr[low];

       /* If there are two elements and first is greater then
          the first element is maximum */
         if ((high == low + 1) && arr[low] >= arr[high])
                return arr[low];

         /* If there are two elements and second is greater then
             the second element is maximum */
             if ((high == low + 1) && arr[low] < arr[high])
                 return arr[high];

               int mid = (low + high)/2; /*low + (high - low)/2;*/

          /* If we reach a point where arr[mid] is greater than both of
           its adjacent elements arr[mid-1] and arr[mid+1], then arr[mid]
            is the maximum element*/
       if ( arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1] && arr[mid] > arr[mid - 1])
            return arr[mid];

       if (arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1] && arr[mid] < arr[mid - 1])
         return findIncre_Decre(arr, low, mid-1);
         else 
        return findIncre_Decre(arr, mid + 1, high);
   }
```

But it is not working for

Input:-

```
arr[]={7,8,9,10,15,5,16}
```

Expected Output:-

```
15
```

But I got answer 16 instead of 15.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question says that the array would be first increasing and then it would be decreasing... but your intput array has collection of random numbers.. seems to be contradictory !

Comment: it is not working because input array doesn't fit to condition `which is first increasing and then decreasing.`

Comment: @MBo sorry , I got it thank you.

Comment: Your array should not contain random numbers. The 16 in your example is out of place. With this setup it is just a matter of finding the largest number in a random array (since the largest number will be surrounded by smaller numbers, this means it is in that particular portion increasing and then decreasing). This is simply a linear search; you can do a form of binary search only if you know the properties of the array well. If it increases and then decreases, without any deviations, binary search will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rafael Giusti said while writing our program we must try to capture invalid input too.

I have added solution to the problem with error handling (max element in array for invalid case). The above problem could be solved by,

1. By linear search (which takes O(n))
2. By binary search (which takes O(longn))

**Linear method**

1.Here for invalid input I'm throwing maximum element in the array

2.And we need minimum of three element in an array for this problem

Note : I'm just checking for edge cases like (less than three elements in the array, array in ascending order, array in descending order). You can iterate the array completely to check whether the given array satisfies the criteria - first increasing - then decreasing which I have not checked in the following program - I'm just returning the maximum element in the array if doesn't satisfy the edge cases.

```
int findElement(int arr[], int low, int high) {
     if(low < 0 || low >= high || low+1 == high) return (arr[low] < arr[high] ? arr[high] : arr[low];
     int max = arr[low];
     for(int i=low+1; i<=high-1 && low-1 <= high; i++) {
         max = arr[i] > max ? arr[i] : max;
         if(arr[i-1] < arr[i] && arr[i] > arr[i+1]) 
            return arr[i];   //Perfect match !!
     }
    return max;    // We haven't found any element 
}
```

**Binary search method**

Note: Returned the maximum value in the array case of invalid input

```
int findElement(int arr[], int low, int high) {
     if(high < low) return arr[low];
     if(high-low < 2) return (arr[low] > arr[high]) ? arr[low] : arr[high];     
     int mid = (low + high)/2;
     int left = findElement(arr, low, mid-1);
     int right = findElement(arr, mid+1, high);
     return (left < arr[mid]) && (right < arr[mid]) ? arr[mid] : (left > right ? left : right);
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. Your linear version only searches for a boundary of increasing/decreasing sequences. It won't find the bad sequence in OP's own test case! It also requires the array to be of size 3 when a simple linear scan and OP's version work for arrays as small as 1. The only way to check for an invalid input is to run the entire array, sequentially verifying each element. Any other alternative will fail if the array is almost correct, but breaks the rule in some part that the algorithm decided not verify because it abandoned first or didn't branch there.

Comment: @giusti The linear search just validates two invalid cases say for example 1) for this problem the array size must be minimum of three and 2) If the sequence is increasing throughout or 3) The given sequence is decreasing through out). And for cases like random sequence of number this will not validate - for which you have to iterate through out the entire array to validate the input array.

Comment: Also, this is not a linear search exact implementation. We are using linear search to solve our problem. Where we have added our validation criteria like the search should work only for array with a minimum length of 3. Hope you understand..

Comment: I understand. But it doesn't make much sense for you to validate only some test cases. Your code returns `-1` if the sequence is `{1, 0, -1, 4}` and `2` if it is `{1, 2, -1, 4}`. Both are invalid inputs, but if the user trusts your function, they'll think one of them is valid. You should either validate and detect errors in a consistent manner or just let the algorithm run from the assumption that the input is valid.

Comment: @giusti the user has given array with positive numbers (my sample accepts and returns for positive numbers). If he/she has negative numbers in array then they must use some other value to validate invalid case..

Answer (score 2):

Why should it work? You wrote the code with the assumption that the array can be segmented into two: one increasing part, and one decreasing part. This test case breaks the pre-conditions.

You could check if the array is valid, but in the worst case it would require a linear scan. It would be preferrable to simply check each element to find the greatest.

Case in point, it's not always good to check if the input is correct. For this particular problem, you have to assume the input is correct if you want to solve it in O(logN).

(**edit**: for fairness, this answer was edited. In the original answer I gave OP a test case to help them find where their code would fail, but my test case was also invalid.)